# EXT.Net custom search combo box trigger on user hit ENTER

Tags: autocomplete, combobox, webforms, asp.net-4.0, ext.net

Is there any sample way to tell Ext.NET combo box to show auto-complete available values on user hit enter.
[I really like advanced search sample of Ext.net combo box sample .](http://examples.ext.net/#/Form/ComboBox/Custom_Search/) In my customization I do data store from SQL and query for searching is pretty heavy ill love to try avoid auto triggering of result set. 
My idea is to allow user to type in query string and hit enter or any hot-key and then to do logic of getting data from sql and allowing user to select available items in showed grid?

My environment is .net4, ASP.NET, WebForms, Ext.Net V2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Our colleges from Ext.Net helped me to solve problem](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?23542-Custom-search-trigered-by-hotkey&p=102932&posted=1#post102932)

```
<ext:ComboBox
    runat="server"
    DisplayField="Common"
    ValueField="Common"
    TypeAhead="false"
    Width="570"
    PageSize="10"
    HideBaseTrigger="true"
    MinChars="10000"
    TriggerAction="Query">
    ...
    <Listeners>
        <SpecialKey Handler="
        if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
            this.doQuery(this.getValue(), true);
        }"></SpecialKey>
    </Listeners>
</ext:ComboBox>
```